# i want to simulate it 500 times but this function gives 187 correct values but after 187 values it give NA values

Tags: r

```
set.seed(1988)

X1<-runif(188)

n<-500

for(i in 1:n){

  logarithem[i]= ifelse (X1[i] <0.5,log (C[i] ) ,(C[i]))

  }
```

Comment: c[i ] contains another data

Comment: You are either unclear on what `?runif` does or how `?ifelse` works. I can't see how this question can help the community. Maybe someone else sees usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
X1<-runif(188)
```

initializes X1 with 188 values.  If you're indexing X1[189], there is an error.

Try this:

```
print (X1[189])
> NA
```

In order to correct it, just change your runif:

```
X1<-runif(500)
```